# Why an interval is lost here when squaring this inequality

Tags: inequality

$$\sqrt{x-2}\geq -1$$

When squaring the inequality I lose the interval [-2,3) why so ?

Comment: Note that the left side is undefined on $[-2,2)$ so you only lose $[2,3)$.

Comment: Try changing $-1$ to $-4$ and see what happens.

Comment: @JMP I seem to loose a much bigger interval

Comment: Now change it to $0$ and then to $1$ or even $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $a\geqslant b$ and $a^2\geqslant b^2$ are not equivalent assertions. Actually, none of them implies the other one.